# How to get the block ID and block title when is rendering

Tags: magento2, static-block

I'd like to add the block ID and the block name among the classes, so I found the file which has the HTML structure.

```
vendor/magento/module-cms/view/frontend/templates/widget/static_block/default.phtml
```

Considering I've the $block object there, how can I get the ID and the title/name of the block?

Comment: please mention in comment if you have fixed this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you should create ***a plugin and after method add your required  and pass to phtml file***.

```
<?php

namespace My\Module\Plugin;

class ChangesPlugin
{


    public function AfterBeforeToHtml(\Magento\Cms\Block\Widget\Block $subject, $result)
    {
        $storeId = $subject->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
         $block = $subject->_blockFactory->create();
         $blockId = $subject->getData('block_id');
         $block->setStoreId($storeId)->load($blockId);

        if($block->isActive()){
            $result->setBlockRelatedData($block);
        }else{
            $result->setBlockRelatedData();

        }
        return $result;
    }
}
?>
```

Now at  `phtml` files you can get `$block->getBlockRelatedData()` relative data
Suppose for title  you can use `$block->getBlockRelatedData()->getTitle()`

Answer (score 0):

`$block->getData('block_id')` does the job for me.